# What are my options - new employer notified me they will not be able to hire me after the contract was signed and zusatzblatt amended

Tags: germany, blue-card, employment

I have received an offer from a new company and singed the contract.
Since I have been in Germany for one year on my blue card, I went through the process of changing my zusatzblatt and received an updated version that says I am to work for my old company until 30 September, and 1 October is my first day at the new company.

The recruiter from a new company reached out to me and informed me they will not be able to take me on board due to funding problems.

Have anyone faced a similar situation? Can I acquire a new contract from another company before 1 October and apply for approval directly?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question about changing your prospective employer. You might, however, consider speaking to a lawyer: German law may allow you to force the defaulting company into employing you as they agreed, or paying damages.

Comment: What does the employment contract you signed say about notice period requirements for termination?

Comment: The notice period is 2 weeks during the probation. I am not keen on forcing a company to employ me - I would rather spend time working for company that wants me working for it. However, I am not sure if changing the employer before the first day of work will affect the process of changing the employer in KVR.